# How do I evaluate this type of integral that involve complex parameters?

Tags: integration, physics, quantum-mechanics

In particular, I am asking about integrals shaped like this:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2-bx}dx$$
where $a\in\mathbb C$ with ${\rm Re}(a)>0$, and $b\in\mathbb C$. This kind of integral appears often in quantum mechanics when computing the wave function using Fourier's transformation. However, it seem that physicists uses the formula
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2-bx}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2+b^2/4a}dy=\frac{e^{b^2/4a}\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt a}$$
which I believe only holds when $a,b$ are real and $a>0$ unless there is further explanation.

Is there any way to justify this formula in the case of $a,b\in\mathbb C$ with ${\rm Re}(a)>0$? Or is there a workaround?

---

**Update: what I feel confused about**

My textbook and an answer below say "make the substitution $y=x+b/2a$". And the integral would be justified by
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(ax^2+bx)} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x^2+(b/a)x)} dx =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a([x+(b/(2a))]^2)} e^{b^2/(4a)} dx\\
=e^{b^2/(4a)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ay^2} dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{b^2/(4a)}$$

(1) After the substitution $y=x+b/2a$, $y$ will not be real if $b/2a$ is not. In this case, shouldn't the integral after the substitution be
$$e^{b^2/(4a)} \int_{-\infty+b/2a}^{\infty+b/2a} e^{-ay^2} dy\quad ?$$
How is this defined? Perhaps a Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

(2) Suppose it is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, this would mean we are integrating
$e^{-ay^2}$, where $a$ and $y$ are both possibly complex, along the line ${\rm Im}(y)={\rm Im}(b/2a)$. How do I evaluate this?

(3) Suppose somehow we can indeed get rid of $b/2a$ and write
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2-bx}dx=e^{b^2/(4a)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ay^2} dy$$
What's to justify
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ay^2} dy=\sqrt{\pi/a}\quad?$$
when $a\notin\mathbb R$? I am assuming another substitution is made here: "$t=\sqrt{a}y$" to obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ay^2} dy=\sqrt{a}\int_L e^{-t^2} dt$$
where $L$ is the line $\mathbb R\cdot\sqrt a$. The well-known $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi}$ does not seem to be usable here.

Comment: Why do you believe that this only holds when $a$ and $b$ are real and $a>0$?

Comment: The derivation needs only Re(a) > 0.  Go through it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: @MichaelBurr It's not that I don't believe it can hold when $a,b$ are complex. I simply need a justification, since the textbook I am reading simply says "make the substitution $y=\sqrt a(x+b/2a)$".

Comment: If you make that substitution, and $a$ is not a positive real, then the limits would change

Comment: A simple computation reduces the problem to the one in which the term $bx$ does not appear: \begin{align}
& ax^2+bx = a\left( x^2 + \frac b a x \right) \\ \\
= {} & a\left( x^2 + \frac ba x + \frac{b^2}{4a^2} \right) - \frac{b^2}{4a} \\ \\
= {} & a\left( x + \frac b {2a} \right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{And then: } & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-ax^2-bx} \, dx \\ \\
= {} & e^{b^2/(4a)} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-a\left( x + \frac b{2z} \right)^2} \, dx \\ \\
= {} & e^{b^2/(4a)} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-au^2} \, du.
\end{align}

Comment: @MichaelHardy I know about this technique, but there are gaps here when $a,b$ are not in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @trisct : If you've done this only when $a\in\mathbb R,$ then you'd want to look at what happens when $a\notin\mathbb R.$ But why would the question of whether $b\in\mathbb r$ matter? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It is whether $b/2a\in\mathbb R$ that matters to me. See (1) in my edited question. Why are you still integrating over $\mathbb R$ after the substitution? Wouldn't this be a problem when $b/2a\notin\mathbb R$? As for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}dx$, I think I can fix it with a complex contour integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather insightful to question whether the substitution is valid because the limits change in a potentially unpleasant way when the substitution is made. Let me show two ways to justify the substitution. First off, we could use contour integrals. Let
$$-ax^2-bx=-a\left(x^2+\frac bax\right)=-a\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2+\frac{b^2}{4a}=-a\left(x+f+ic\right)^2+\frac{b^2}{4a}$$
Where $f=\Re\frac b{2a}$ and $c=\Im \frac b{2a}$. Translation in the real direction doesn't change the limits but translation in the imaginary direction does:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2-bx}dx=e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(x+f+ic)^2}dx=e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(y+ic)^2}dy$$
Where we have made the substitution $x+f=y$. To justify the imaginary translation we set up a contour integral
$$\oint_Ca^{-az^2}dz=\int_{C_1}e^{-az^2}dz+\int_{C_2}e^{-az^2}dz+\int_{C_3}e^{-az^2}dz+\int_{C_4}e^{-az^2}dz$$
Where the contour $C$ is counterclockwise around a rectangle in the complex $z$-plane and the subcontours are shown in the following figure:
[image: fig 1]
Now we can work out the integral over each subcontour. Along $C_1$, $z=t$ so
$$\int_{C_1}e^{-az^2}dz=\int_{-N}^Ne^{-at^2}dt$$
So
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C_1}e^{-az^2}dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-at^2}dt$$
Along $C_2$, $z=N+is$ so
$$\int_{C_2}e^{-az^2}dz=i\int_0^ce^{-a(N+is)^2}ds$$
$$\begin{align}-a(N+is)^2&=-(\Re a+i\Im a)(N^2+2iNs-s^2)\\
&=-(N^2-s^2)\Re a+2Ns\Im a+i\left(-(N^2-s^2)\Im a-2Ns\Re a\right)\end{align}$$
So
$$\left|e^{-a(N+is)^2}\right|=e^{-(N^2-s^2)\Re a+2Ns\Im a}$$
And
$$\begin{align}\left|\int_{C_2}e^{-az^2}dz\right|&\le\int_0^ce^{-(N^2-s^2)\Re a+2Ns\Im a}ds\\
&\le\int_0^ce^{-(N^2-c^2)\Re a+2Nc\left|\Im a\right|}ds=ce^{-(N^2-c^2)\Re a+2Nc\left|\Im a\right|}\end{align}$$
So that
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C_2}e^{-az^2}dz=0$$
Along $C_3$, $z=t+ic$ so
$$\int_{C_3}e^{-az^2}dz=\int_N^{-N}e^{-a(t+ic)^2}dt=-\int_{-N}^Ne^{-a(t+ic)^2}dt$$
So
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C_3}e^{-az^2}dz=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(t+ic)^2}dt$$
From the work surround the $C_2$ contour I hope it is clear that
$$\left|\int_{C_4}e^{-az^2}dz\right|\le ce^{-(N^2-c^2)\Re a+2Nc\left|\Im a\right|}$$
So
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C_4}e^{-az^2}dz=0$$
Since the integrand is holomorphic along and within contour $C$ it follows that
$$\oint_Ce^{-az^2}dz=0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-at^2}dt+0-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(t+ic)^2}dt+0$$
So that justifies the imaginary translation step:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-at^2}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(t+ic)^2}dt$$
Of course we only did it for $c=\Im\frac b{2a}>0$ you might have to repeat for $c<0$. So we are up to
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^3-bx}dx=e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=2e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx$$
Now we let $a=re^{i\theta}$ and set up another contour integral
[image: fig 2]
We want to do
$$\oint_Ce^{-rz^2}dz=\int_{C_1}e^{-rz^2}dz+\int_{C_2}e^{-rz^2}dz+\int_{C_3}e^{-rz^2}dz$$
Along $C_1$, $z=t$ so
$$\int_{C_1}e^{-rz^2}dz=\int_0^Re^{-rt^2}dt$$
and
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C_1}e^{-rz^2}dz=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-rt^2}dt=\frac1{\sqrt r}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}r}$$
Along $C_2$, $z=Re^{i\phi}$ so
$$\int_{C_2}e^{-rz^2}dz=\int_0^{\frac{\theta}2}e^{-rR^2e^{2i\phi}}iRe^{i\phi}d\phi$$
Then
$$-rR^2e^{2i\phi}=-rR^2\cos2\phi-irR^2\sin2\phi$$
So
$$\left|e^{-rR^2e^{2i\phi}}\right|=e^{-rR^2\cos2\phi}\le e^{-rR^2\cos2\theta}$$
Thus
$$\int_{C_2}e^{-rz^2}\le\int_0^{\frac{\theta}2}Re^{-rR^2\cos3\theta}d\phi=\frac{\theta}2Re^{-rR^2\cos3\theta}$$
And
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C_2}e^{-rz^2}dz=0$$
Along $C_3$, $z=te^{i\theta/2}$ so
$$\int_{C_3}e^{-rz^2}dz=e^{\frac{i\theta}2}\int_R^0e^{-re^{i\theta}t^2}dt=-e^{\frac{i\theta}2}\int_0^Re^{-at^2}dt$$
So
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C_3}e^{-rz^2}dz=-e^{\frac{i\theta}2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-at^2}dt$$
Again the integrand is holomorphic along and within contour $C$ so
$$\oint_Ce^{-rz^2}dz=0=\frac1{\sqrt r}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt+0-e^{\frac{i\theta}2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-at^2}dt$$
So now we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2-bx}dx=\frac{2e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt re^{\frac{i\theta}2}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=\frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$$
Another way to justify is to start with
$$I(c)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(y+ic)^2}dy$$
Then
$$\frac{dI}{dc}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-2ia(y+ic)e^{-a(y+ic)^2}dy=\left.ie^{-a(y+ic)^2}\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$$
So
$$I(c)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(y+ic)^2}dy=\text{constant}=I(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ay^2}dy$$
That gets us to
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^3-bx}dx=2e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx$$
Now we can let
$$J(\theta)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-re^{i\theta}x^2}dx$$
Then
$$\frac{dJ}{d\theta}=\int_0^{\infty}-rie^{i\theta}x^2e^{-re^{i\theta}x^2}dx=\left.\frac i2xe^{-re^{i\theta}x^2}\right|_0^{\infty}-\frac i2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-re^{i\theta}x^2}dx=-\frac i2J(\theta)$$
The general solution to this differential equation is
$$J(\theta)=Ce^{-\frac i2\theta}$$
And we can apply the initial condition
$$J(0)=C=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-rx^2}dx=\frac1{\sqrt r}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$$
If we now let $a=re^{i\theta}$ then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2-bx}dx=2e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}J(\theta)=\frac{2e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt re^{\frac i2\theta}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=\frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$$
So we could justify the imaginary translation step and the rotation step either via contour integrals or by differentiating with respect to a parameter.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is directly to the point. But allow me to ask further: Is it true that all such translations can be ignored, as long as the integrand is bounded along the translated line (as in the comment by Dr Zafar Ahmed Dsc)?

Comment: No, it's a damned lie! Take $f(z)=\frac1{(z-ic/2)(z+i)^2}$. Then in my rectangular contour integral $$\oint_Cf(z)dz=-\frac{2\pi i}{(1+c/2)^2}\ne0$$ so the integrals above and below the singularity at $z=ic/2$ will not be the same.

Comment: Great example. Perhaps he meant an integrand with no pole?

Comment: Perhaps. But it's still tricky in that case because you can't necessarily take it as a given that the $C_2$ and $C_4$ integrals go to zero because there are integrals which converge without the integrand approaching zero. For example $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt2}$ which you could get by letting $r=1$ and evaluating $J(\pi/2)$ in my proof by differentiating with respect to a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(ax^2+bx)} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x^2+(b/a)x)} dx =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a([x+(b/(2a))]^2)} e^{b^2/(4a)} dx $$ 
Let $x+b/(2a)=t$, then
$$I=e^{b^2/(4a)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-at^2} dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{b^2/(4a)}, ~\Re(a) >0.$$

Comment: Usually $\frac{b}{2a} \notin \mathbb{R}$ when $a$ and $b$ are complex.

Comment: it does not matter as long as $\Re a >0$, if not then the integral diverges. Also the value of this integral is in general complex when $a$ and $b$ are complex.

Comment: I don't see why wouldn't it matter. You are integrating along the real line even after the substitution, which does not seem to be right, unless $\frac{b}{2a} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There are two gaps I don't understand. (1) When you make the substitution $t=x+b/2a$, if $b/2a$ is not real, then $t$ is not real, shouldn't the integral be $\int_{-\infty+b/2a}^{\infty+b/2a}(\cdots)dt$ now? (2) How do you justify $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-at^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi/a}$ when $a$ is complex (actually I think $t$ is also complex)?

Comment: @Botond Yes! Exactly what I am asking here.

Comment: One may note that $\int_{-\infty+ic}^{\infty+ic} f(x) dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ provided $f(d+ic)$ is finite (real or complex). This integration is along a horizontal line $y=c$ line paralel $x$ axis. This lies behind evaluation of this complex valued integral.

Comment: Can you elaborate? This is what I am looking for...rather than what is currently in your answer.