# Let $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ exist, state when $J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+ic) dx=I, c \in R $

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration

Currently, a question in MSE:
[How do I evaluate this type of integral that involve complex parameters?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572119/how-do-i-evaluate-this-type-of-integral-that-involve-complex-parameters/3572145#3572145)
gives rise to the following query:

Let $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ exist and let $J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+ic) dx, c \in R. $
The question is when $J=I.$

To re-emphasize that the argument of the integrand in $J$  has an imaginary shift to that of $I$. Can there be a simple and straight forward criterion on $f(x)$ and $c$,  so that $J=I$?

Comment: There are several criterions. When applicable you can use residuum theorem on large semicircles. Provided for example that the same poles are contained in the two integrations. But you also need the integral on the arcs to go to zero

Comment: Thanks, but I am ;ooking for more direct and transparent criterion.

Comment: If $f(x+it) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$ uniformly  for $t$ between $0$ and $c$ the the equality holds.

Comment: @lcv... I would use the residue theorem on a long, thin rectangle ... one long side from $-R to +R$ and the other long side from $-R+ic$ to $+R+ic$.  If there are no residues in there, and $f$ goes to zero on the short sides as $R \to +\infty$, then we get the result.  This explains Kavi's criterion.

Comment: Yes, I also think similarly, thanks. May be there is something more to it.